# Max pooled connection timeout

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have this web app and my users often seem to be getting this error when logging in:

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached. "

My login function is as follows:

```
Public Function login(userName As String, password As String) As Boolean
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AvailDBConnection").ToString)
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT UserID, Password FROM [Users] WHERE UserID = @user AND Password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS= @password;", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)

            da.SelectCommand = cmd

            conn.Open()
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        If dt.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If


    End Function
```

I wrote to my hosting provider about this and they said:

> Hello,
>
> It looks like the memory leakage.
>
> Please review.

Anyway, I did review.

As I understand it, memory leakage occurs when data is stored in memory and never disposed of. For example, if I have an infinite loop adding items to an array, then eventually, the system is going to run out of memory.

However, as I understand it, once I'm out of scope, in many languages, including VB.net, the garbage collectors automatically clear any data that is no longer in use. For example, if I declare a variable within a Sub, once that sub ends, if I am not using it anywhere else, that variable and the space reserved for it is gone.

In my case, in the login function, since only a Boolean is returned and I'm not assigning any variables inside the function to variables outside the function, all other variables declared in the function, such as conn, da, cmd, dt, etc. will be cleared by the garbage collector once the function is over (end function, return true or return false). Since Booleans are only one bit and there is no infinite loop or anything, I don't see how there can be a memory leak in this function.

I do not believe it has to do with memory leaks but rather that it is running out of SQL server connections. I thought I might have been opening many DB connections but not closing them, but with the "using" blocks, the connections will always close, even in the case of an exception.

Could this also be caused by an unclosed connection elsewhere in a separate instance of my app?  I don't want to paste my whole app but I use a similar technique in my other DB functions.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to review everywhere you create a new connection.  The login method you posted is fine, it uses `Using` as it's supposed to.  Likely you have other code somewhere else that is not using `Using` and thus leaking connections.

Comment: I had previously gone through all of my functions and put in using blocks, except for one. That one was problematic.  It may, for whatever reason try to insert a row with a duplicate primary key. In such a case I didn't want it to freak out but just move on.  I used on error resume next, which I know is bad form and it also didn't work with using blocks.  Instead I wrapped the execute statement in a try block and in catch, I put " If ex.Number <> 2627 Then Throw ex"  That oughtta do it.  Hard to test cause it's intermittent.  But Imma try to get my friends to hammer it hard!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set poll limit to false in web config settings :

```
web.cofig:
<add name="ApplicationDs" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=sa;Password=xxx;pooling=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: No, don't do this.  Turning off pooling hides the problem and creates a new one--without pooling acquiring new connections will take significantly longer and slow down your application.

Comment: Still, I would rather a slow app than an app that crashes all the time.

Comment: @JonasGraham, better to fix the leaking connections.